How to use AWS secret manager on Serverless and Nestjs
I have a NestJS API and i deploy it on AWS with Serverless.
I would like to use AWS Secret Manager to store sensitive data like api_key then use it in my code as env variable.
I tried this on my serverless file
custom: 
  my_env_var: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/my_env_var}

functions:
 main:
  environment:
    API_KEY: ${self:custom.my_env_var.API_KEY}

But then i got: (Cannot resolve variable at "functions.main.environment.API_KEY": Value not found at "self" source)
Do you know how can i do this ?
Then, how can i use it on my nestJS ?
Thanks by advance for the help's

add this one ${aws:secretsmanager:SECRET_NAME}

I use parameter Store instead of Secret Manager and it worked
